# How are results sorted when the query is empty?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, azure-cognitive-search

I can't find any informations on [Azure Search documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/dn798928.aspx)  about how the results are sorted when the query sent is empty. I've also read the  [Empty Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/empty-search.html) section of `ElasticSearch` but still can't find any answer.

Is this sorting by Key?

Is the backend sending a batch of parallel requests and concatenate the results since the sorting doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of empty query, the sort order is unspecified. You cannot rely on any particular order. If you need a specific order, ask for it using orderby query parameter. 
HTH,
Eugene

Comment: It's like an anti-answer. :) You work on Azure Search Service and your answer for this question is "you cannot rely on any particular order".

Comment: Is this because revealing how it is ordered would give too much information about algorithms used by the service? Actually, what I need to know is if this random order is good enough for a backend I've developped to avoid adding a layer of randomness in the search. Ex. Query="" and SortBy=Key.

Comment: This is because relying on incidental implementation details that are prone to change with time is always dangerous :) I don't think you can use this to enforce randomness, because the order might not change across multiple queries (e.g., query results could be cached).

Comment: My feeling is that the engine favors parallelization when receiving an empty query with no filter and that the result is made from asynchronously received arrays sorted by their internal keys. I find interesting the fact you mentioned: that the query could be cached (though an index changes too allows caching?) could make the service returns always the same documents, penalizing other documents and preventing them to get new "hits". In the other hand, this semi-randomness is better than sorting by Guid, since sorting by Guid (if the key is a guid) would always present the data the same way.